# Alternative for hashmap

Tags: java

I have a hashmap which has several values and it override the same keys, is there any solution for this? this is my Hashmap

```
 HashMap<String, String> meMap=new HashMap<String, String>();
 meMap.put("Jack","John");
 meMap.put("Jack","Jacob");
```

it will override the first one.

Comment: There is no concept of order in a HashMap. So, when you say "I want to get the third one", that doesn't make sense in this data structure. Maybe you want a LinkedList instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use get function: `meMap.get("Color3")`;. You can access to different methods of maps in Java here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Answer (score 1):

A Map is a Key - Value store, meaning that you access values in the Map by specifying its Key. So you would do:

```
meMap.get("Color3");
```

Comment: sorry I made a mistake all keys have the same key "Color"

Comment: In a Map, there are no duplicate keys. So since all keys have the same value Color, there will just be 1 key with value equal to its last set value.

Comment: yeah one key and several values

Comment: how to get the third one?

Comment: There is only one value for the key. It is not possible to have one key for multiple values. What I am saying is that the previous value of they key will be overwritten when you write to the same key.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `get()` for single element:

```
Toast.makeText(context, map.get("Color3"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Map has combination of  `Key` and `value`. If you want a value, you have to call it's key.

```
System.out.println(meMap.get("Color3"));
```

### Resource Link:

[Class HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can not have multiple values for one key in HashMap.

If you need to store multiple values for same key then you should use map insted of HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment,it seems you want to store multiple values for a single key.In that case you can store your values in a List and then add that list to the map,as shown below:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> meMap=new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> lst=new ArrayList<String>();//List to store colors
        lst.add("Red");
        lst.add("Blue");
        lst.add("Green");
        lst.add("White");
        //add the key and list to map
        meMap.put("Color",lst);
        //to get the value at 3rd position,use get(2),as index starts from 0. 
        System.out.println(meMap.get("Color").get(2));
```